# How to fix "error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector" in macros in c language?

Tags: c

I have such code:

```c
typedef struct dArrString
{
    char** arr;
    int locLength;
    int length;
} dArrString;

#define D_ARR_STRING(NAME, ARR_STRING)\
    NAME.arr = (char**) malloc(0 * sizeof(char*))\
    NAME.locLength = 2;\
    NAME.length = 0;\
    printf("%s", ARR_STRING[0]);


int main()
{
    dArrString stos;
    char emptyStr = {'\0'};
    D_ARR_STRING(;stos, emptyStr);

    return 0;
}
```

Problem is in **ARR_STRING[0]** in D_ARR_STRING macros, becuse after compiling this code I got such an error:

error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
printf("%s", ARR_STRING[0]);

How can I fix this or what should I change to?

Comment: What is that first semicolon in `D_ARR_STRING(;stos, emptyStr);` supposed to achieve?

Comment: I don't know what `malloc(0)` does, but it won't give you any memory.

Comment: `char emptyStr = {'\0'};` does not declare an array, just a single character.

Comment: Even if you made `emptyStr` an array, `printf("%s", ARR_STRING[0]);` is still wrong because `ARR_STRING[0]` would be `emptyStr[0]` which is a single character, and `%s` is for printing strings.

Answer (score 1):

`ARR_STRING` is the second parameter to the macro, which is passed as `emptyStr`.

`emptyStr` is declared as a `char`:

```
char emptyStr = {'\0'};
```

meaning that it is one single Character (like `A`, or `Z`).

The compiler is correct that you are trying to take the subscript (`[ ]`) of `emptyStr`, and `emptyStr` is not an array, nor a pointer, nor a vector.

If you want to fix it, you need to make the second parameter an array.
Most probably, you want:

```
char emptyStr[50] = "";  // I'm not sure what size you need, so I made it 50.
```

---

#### List of problems:

- You have a weird semi-colon before `stos` for no clear reason.
- You are calling `malloc` for 0 bytes.
- You are treating variable `emptyStr`, a single `char`, like its an array of characters.
- You have a substantial block of code in a macro for no good reason, when a function would do just fine.

Comment: Thank you, if I will not add ; before stos, I will have an error: "error: expected ';' before 'stos'" I want in the future realloc malloc, that is way I did 0. And yes, problem was in emptyStr that I didn't write size of it, that is emptyStr[][32]. Macros I use, because I don't want to write every time malloc function. Can you say, why I get "error: expected ';' before 'stos'" without ; before stos var ?